# How do I downgrade a package?

Tags: firefox, downgrade

I just upgraded to Firefox 5 to find out that [Selenium does not work on it](http://www.google.com.ph/search?aq=f&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=capybara+firefox+5). I'd like to downgrade to Firefox 4 but haven't found a way to do this.

**How do you downgrade to Firefox 4 on 11.04?**

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Start "Synaptic Package Manager"
2. Type in "firefox" in the quick filter and highlight it in the search result (the one w/ the green box next to the package name indicating that it is already installed on your computer)
3. Select from the menubar "Package" -> "Force Version"

   [image: Package Force Version]
4. Select 4.0 from the dropped down list "4.0+nobinonly-0ubuntu3 (natty)" and click "Force Version"

   [image: Force Version]
5. "Apply" changes

   [image: Apply]

Comment: +1 downgrading from 9 to 7 works. THX!

Answer (score 0):

you can install firefox with repository .

and download firefox from firefox.com and run it .

```
Download Firefox from the Firefox download page to your home directory.
Open a Terminal and go to your home directory: cd ~
Extract the contents of the downloaded file:tar xjf firefox-*.tar.bz2
Close Firefox if it's open.
To start Firefox, run the firefox script in the firefox folder.
```

~/firefox/firefox

Firefox should now start. You can then create an icon on your desktop to run this command.

Comment: This would be best if I were to open them normally (ie. clicking a button to launch the browser). However, since I'll be using Selenium which programmatically launches the browser, I'm afraid I'll need to remove FF5, and install FF4 to keep this simple. Thanks!

Comment: I ended up using this method, thanks. I couldn't find a link to download FF4.0 in firefox.com, so I just URL-hacked it. I changed `5.0` to `4.0` in the FF 5.0 download URL. Then, so that the system launches 4.0 instead of 5.0, I unpacked it into /usr/lib/firefox-4.0 and made a symlink `/usr/lib/firefox ~> /usr/lib/firefox-4.0/firefox`.