# Downgrade Firefox 7 to FF6

Tags: firefox, package-management, downgrade

System: Ubuntu 10.04

For testing purposes I need to downgrade from FF7 to FF6. 
I'm aware of this answer: [How do I downgrade a package?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/49966/how-to-downgrade-to-firefox-4-on-11-04) but my Synaptic Package Manager only offers me 7.01, 3.6.3 and 3.6.23 when I go to "Force Version". How is this best achieved?

Answer (score 1):

You can try following:
Download binary of required FF version from [this ftp](ftp://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/releases/6.0/), unpack it somewhere in Your home folder, and run it from there.