# how to upgrade to firefox 12 not 13 on ubuntu

Tags: upgrade, firefox, version

Yesterday my Firefox was upgraded from 12 to 13 and I downgraded it back following [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/49966/how-to-downgrade-to-firefox-4-on-11-04), specifically `12.0+build1-0ubunut0.11.04.1` not `4.0+nobinonly-0ubuntu3 (natty)`. Besides the new version 13, there was only one other selection, my previous version 12. Today, Firefox got upgraded again and so I followed the same steps but instead of version 12(there was only one other version besides 13 again), it must have been version 4 because my Firefox is now version 4 and there isn't the version 12 selection.

How do I get back to the version 12 I had? I don't want 13(some things break on it) and definitely don't want version 4. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First remove the firefox installed on your pc by typing in terminal
`sudo apt-get remove --purge firefox`

Then download these packages (from the official firefox ppa).
I have assumed that you have natty.

**For 32 bit**

[firefox 12 main](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-mozilla-security/+archive/ppa/+build/3426145/+files/firefox_12.0%2Bbuild1-0ubuntu0.11.04.1_i386.deb)

[firefox mozsymbols](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-mozilla-security/+archive/ppa/+build/3426145/+files/firefox-mozsymbols_12.0%2Bbuild1-0ubuntu0.11.04.1_i386.deb)

[firefox locale_en](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-mozilla-security/+archive/ppa/+build/3426145/+files/firefox-locale-en_12.0%2Bbuild1-0ubuntu0.11.04.1_i386.deb)

[firefox gnome support](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-mozilla-security/+archive/ppa/+build/3426145/+files/firefox-gnome-support_12.0%2Bbuild1-0ubuntu0.11.04.1_i386.deb)

[firefox global menu](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-mozilla-security/+archive/ppa/+build/3426145/+files/firefox-globalmenu_12.0%2Bbuild1-0ubuntu0.11.04.1_i386.deb)

[firefox branding](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-mozilla-security/+archive/ppa/+build/3426145/+files/firefox-branding_12.0%2Bbuild1-0ubuntu0.11.04.1_i386.deb)

**For 64 bit**

[firefox 12 main](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-mozilla-security/+archive/ppa/+build/3426143/+files/firefox_12.0%2Bbuild1-0ubuntu0.11.04.1_amd64.deb)

[firefox mozsymbols](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-mozilla-security/+archive/ppa/+build/3426143/+files/firefox-mozsymbols_12.0%2Bbuild1-0ubuntu0.11.04.1_amd64.deb)

[firefox locale_en](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-mozilla-security/+archive/ppa/+build/3426143/+files/firefox-locale-en_12.0%2Bbuild1-0ubuntu0.11.04.1_amd64.deb)

[firefox gnome support](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-mozilla-security/+archive/ppa/+build/3426143/+files/firefox-gnome-support_12.0%2Bbuild1-0ubuntu0.11.04.1_amd64.deb)

[firefox global menu](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-mozilla-security/+archive/ppa/+build/3426143/+files/firefox-globalmenu_12.0%2Bbuild1-0ubuntu0.11.04.1_amd64.deb)

[firefox branding](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-mozilla-security/+archive/ppa/+build/3426143/+files/firefox-branding_12.0%2Bbuild1-0ubuntu0.11.04.1_amd64.deb)

Comment: @Ashu Hi, I think I found it only the main so far, but when I tried to install it, it says: Error: Breaks existing package 'hunspell-en-ca' that conflict: 'iceweasel'. But the '/home/jc/Downloads/firefox_12.0+build1-0ubuntu0.11.04.1_amd64.deb' provides it via: 'gnome-www-browser,iceweasel,www-browser' and won't let me install

Comment: @Ashu I have already removed firefox, is there a specific order of installation?

Comment: try this `sudo apt-get remove --purge iceweasel`

Comment: also put all the files in one folder then cd into the folder and type `dpkg -i *.deb`

Comment: Hi, I appreciate your help. I put them all in one folder and ran the command, now I am getting: Errors were encountered while processing:
 firefox-gnome-support-dbg,  Package firefox-dbg is not installed.

Comment: Instead of going through the software center (double clicking the debs), I ran the dpkg command, in addition to the ones you gave, did I need one more firefox-dbg deb file?

Comment: k forget that package i just included it extra. You can delete that file

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3696/discussion-between-jenny-carter-and-ashu)